# Сокет-сервер на java

Tags: java, сервер, сокет

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как можно создать сокет-сервер для связи сокет-клиентом (телефоном на андроид) на Java через глобальную сеть интернет? На данный момент у меня есть сокет-клиент и сервер на Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Я, конечно, может не правильно понял вас, но подключаться к серверу так `Socket s = new Socket(ADDRESS, PORT);`, где ADDRESS это ip сервера, а PORT, соответственно его порт.

На стороне сервера должно быть это

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ADDRESS);
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, 0, address);
```

В моем случае в `ADDRESS` на стороне сервера была строка "localhost".

Comment: Я делала так,но у меня ничего не получилось,клиент к серверу не подключается.Я сохраняю файл с расширением Java и запускаю через командную строку,может я неправильно запускаю?(скорее всего, я задаю глупые вопросы,просто я никогда не имела опыта создания сервера до этого момента:))

Comment: Скачайте какую-нибудь IDE и через нее пытайтесь что-то сделать. А то, как я понимаю, у вас ее нет.